# Very fast sampling from a set with fixed number of elements in python

Tags: python, performance, random, numpy, random-access

I need to sample uniformly at random a number from a set with fixed size, do some calculation, and put the new number back into the set. (The number samples needed is very large)

I've tried to store the numbers in a list and use random.choice() to pick an element, remove it, and then append the new element. But that's way too slow!

I'm thinking to store the numbers in a numpy array, sample a list of indices, and for each index perform the calculation.

- Are there any faster way of doing this process?

Comment: Are you partitioning your collection into two pieces?  Those that get processed (a fixed size) and those that are not processed?  Why are you "replacing"?  Why not build a new collection from the two sub-collections?  'a= (f(x) for x in S[:limit]) + (x for x in s[limit:])` If `s` is shuffled, this should work, right?  Why do "replacement" into a list?

Comment: The calculation on each element depends on other elements on the list, I don't know of any ways to vectorize such a process.

Comment: "calculation on each element depends on other elements on the list"? Please explain that, too.  Depending on other elements does not force you into a replacement-style process.  Please provide the code you're using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python lists are implemented internally as arrays (like Java `ArrayList`s, C++ `std::vector`s, etc.), so removing an element from the middle is relatively slow: all subsequent elements have to be reindexed. (See http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-list-implementation/ for more on this.) Since the order of elements doesn't seem to be relevant to you, I'd recommend you just use `random.randint(0, len(L) - 1)` to choose an index `i`, then use `L[i] = calculation(L[i])` to update the `i`th element.

Answer (score 4):

> I need to sample uniformly at random a number from a set with fixed
>   size, do some calculation, and put the new number back into the set.

```
s = list(someset)           # store the set as a list
while 1:
    i = randrange(len(s))   # choose a random element
    x = s[i]
    y = your_calculation(x) # do some calculation
    s[i] = y                # put the new number back into the set
```

Comment: Why isn't this `s[i] = your_calculation( s[i] )`?  Why all the separate assignment statements?

Comment: For clarity, so the OP can see clearly that each clause in his problem specification corresponds with a line of code that implements that clause.

Answer (score 2):

[random](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html).sample( 
a set or list or Numpy array, Nsample )
is very fast,
but it's not clear to me if you want anything like this:

```
import random

Setsize = 10000
Samplesize = 100
Max = 1 << 20
bigset = set( random.sample( xrange(Max), Setsize ))  # initial subset of 0 .. Max

def calc( aset ):
    return set( x + 1 for x in aset )  # << your code here

    # sample, calc a new subset of bigset, add it --
for iter in range(3):
    asample = random.sample( bigset, Samplesize )
    newset = calc( asample )  # new subset of 0 .. Max
    bigset |= newset
```

You could use Numpy arrays
or [bitarray](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray)
instead of `set`, but I'd expect the time in calc() to dominate.

What are your Setsize and Samplesize, roughly ?