# fast way to uniformly remove 10% of all the elements in a given list of python

Tags: python

This question is two-folded. Firstly, for my understanding, the idea to uniformly remove 10% from a given  list is like the following. 
(1): count the 10% * totul number of elements
(2): randomly and uniformly remove element one by one until the number of elements in the list is at most 90% * totul number of elements
     I.e.,

```
while (the current number of elements is bigger than 90% * totul number of elements)
            randomly and uniformly generate an element from the current list and remove it.
```

Is the above correct? Does this more sound like without replacement? Or is there any built-in python function I can use. 
Secondly, following this link, [Very fast sampling from a set with fixed number of elements in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815263/very-fast-sampling-from-a-set-with-fixed-number-of-elements-in-python)
I got the idea that removing elements from a list in python is costly. So, is there any better way to get around this? Many thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by uniformly?

Comment: means every element has the equal probability to be choosen.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like `random.sample` would be the way to go...

```
n_elements = int(len(elements) * 0.9)
randomly_selected = random.sample(elements, n_elements)
```

This gets around the "removing elements from a list in python is costly" problem by creating a new list instead.

Answer (score 2):

I did this by getting how big 90% of the list is, `random.shuffle`ing the list, then reassigning the list from the beginning through `n` (90% of the list).

```
n = int(len(elements) * 0.9)
random.shuffle(elements)
elements = elements[:n]
```