# use np.random.multinomial() in python

Tags: python, random

I have a task to randomly chose 100 element from a population of alpha list [a,b,c,d] with corresponding frequency (probability) [0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4]. 
There are many different ways to do it. But here I want what returned after this function call (suppose there is one) is a list of the number of elements chosen. Say, it returns (20,20,30,30), then it means 20 of elements a are chosen, 20 of elements c are chosen, etc. 
I figured that  np.random.multinomial is the way to go. Following the above example, I will need to call the function np.random.multinomial(100, [0.1,0.3,0.2,0.4],1 ). Is this right ? Thanks.

Related:
[fast way to uniformly remove 10% of all the elements in a given list of python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28975484/fast-way-to-uniformly-remove-10-of-all-the-elements-in-a-given-list-of-python)

Comment: For the implementation purpose, I hope this is correct. But I sensed that something is wrong. Because the multinomial distribution is more like choose with replacement, since the probability is given and fixed in the first place. What I want for this question is more like choosing without replacement, right ?

Comment: Each of your 100 elements will belong to one of the 4 categories in the end, with the given probability. There is no notion of replacement here since you are not choosing but assigning. Think of it as a tree with a probability on each branch.

Comment: what is the difference between choosing and assigning ?

Comment: There are two different questions. You don't need categories to choose out of 100 elements. Choose 10 out of 100: `np.random.choice(range(100),10)`, and you can add `replace=False` to draw without replacement. But what you want to do here (and do with the multinomial) is equivalent to `np.random.choice(range(4),100, replace=True, p=[0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4])`

Comment: So, range(4) means there are 4 categories ? np.random.choice(range(4),100, replace=True, p=[0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4]) means out of the 4 categories, we are going to choose 100 elements ? Generally, we do not care about how many elements are in the whole population ? (suppose the whole population is the population we want to choose 100 elements from). Is this right ?

Comment: It is confusing. I run np.random.choice(range(4),100, replace=False, p=[0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4]) and got an error: Cannot take a larger sample than population when 'replace=False'

Comment: That is why a previous comment - that got erased - was saying: you cannot draw 100 out of 4 without replacement. If it is confusing, go back to the multinomial only. And do not care about replacement, you were doing the right thing already. Think of the multinomial process as a tree, with only 1 element to classify; then repeat the process 100 times.

Comment: Thanks very much, muraveill. I worked around by using random.sample. Thanks again.

Comment: Note that it is not doing the same thing at all, since with `sample` you know exactly how many you get in the end (not random). And sampling makes no sense if the elements are indistinguishable, it is simpler to just say 1:10 is group 1, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `np.random.multinomial(100, [0.1,0.3,0.2,0.4], 1 )` is correct. But since you are doing only one draw you'd maybe prefer the simpler `np.random.multinomial(100, [0.1,0.3,0.2,0.4])` (without the `,1`) which returns an array instead of an array of (one) array.

Comment: did you see my comment ? What I want is to uniformly and randomly choose 100 elements from a population with 10% element a, 30% element b, 20% element c and 40% element d. It's chosen without replacement.

Comment: The choice you make is the choice of the category (one out of four, and you choose 100 times), not the individual, and it is with replacement. The individuals are not chosen but assigned to one of the categories.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with JulienD.   The word "choose" and the given probabilities just don't go together.

- When use "choose", we mean permutation without order.
- When use probabilities given, we mean these are constant probabilities (unless it is stated that it is conditional).   So the items are "assigned" to categories with the given probabilities.

Of course, the count in the categories is not 100*probabilities.  That would have been the expected value over the long run.   Just like if you toss a fair coin, you don't expect it to be HTHTHT...HT.    But over the long run the count of H will be half of total tosses.

```
import numpy.random as npr
npr.seed(123)
npr.multinomial(100, [0.1,0.3,0.2,0.4], 1)
# Out: array([[11, 27, 18, 44]])
```

As the number of simulations increases, the probability will converge to the given probabilities.

```
simulations = 1000
sum(npr.multinomial(100, [0.1,0.3,0.2,0.4], simulations))/simulations/100
#Out:array([ 0.09995,  0.29991,  0.19804,  0.4021 ])
```